# How to select documents based on _id and another field in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am pretty new to Mongo, I have collection

```
{ 
    "_id" : "297637", 
    "polygon" : {
        "1" : {
            "direction5" : {
                "lat" : 40.73279100000004, 
                "lon" : -74.027161, 
                "delivery_fee" : NumberInt(300), 
                "delivery_estimate" : NumberInt(45), 
                "delivery_offered_to_diner_location" : false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I wanted query to select all documents which has _ID=297637 AND POLYGON=1
mean select all rows of "direction1", "direction2", "direction3" etc  inside the POLYGON=1

I have tried

```
{ $and: [ { "_id": "297637" }, { "polygon": "1" } ] }
```

But it doesnt show any results.

Maybe its because `polygon` and `1` are type of `Object` or what?

[image]

Comment: Could you paste your document here ?

Comment: @mickl added.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `{ "polygon": "1" }` because this statement checks if `polygon` field is equal to `"1"` while in your document it is nested object with one field `"1"`.

In MongoDB all `_id` fields are unique which means that `db.col.find({_id: "297637"})` will give you only one document. However if you still want to check `polygon` and get zero or one result you can check if path `"polygon.1"` exists in your document using [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator.

```
db.col.find({_id: "297637", "polygon.1": { $exists: true } })
```

Alternatively you can check if `polygon.1` is an object using [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/index.html) operator:

```
db.col.find({_id: "297637", "polygon.1": { $type: "object" } });
```